# Ad causing mixed content in HTTPS

Tags: support, advertising, ssl

Since Stack Overflow is [officially HTTPS](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/), I was sad to see a mixed content warning from an ad.

[image]

Can we fix the ad to use HTTPS too?

The offending URL is a tracking pixel in a frame from this ad.

[image]

Comment: Did you happen to get a screenshot of the offending ad? Our advertisers are all *supposed* to be using HTTPS now...

Comment: @Oded This actually looks like a tracking pixel if you [navigate to the offending URL](http://bcp.crwdcntrl.net/5/c=10025/camp_int=Advertiser-131179%5ECampaign-770722%5Eimpressions).

Comment: I guess some advertisers don't understand mixed content.

Comment: Hmm... unfortunately just the tracking pixel isn't enough to isolate the advertiser, campaign, or creative in question. Can you provide *anything* else to help us figure this one out?

Comment: @stevvve reproduced it again. See edit.

Comment: Perfecccccccccccct, @vcsjones! On it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Reaching out to the client now to get this fixed. The ads have been turned off in the meantime, so you shouldn't see these warnings anymore. As always, appreciate the heads up!

UPDATE

The ads have been fixed and are now live again.

Comment: When Nick turns the CSP on, this will be sooooooooo fun.

Comment: @Braiam I'm prepped to activate reporting for upgrade insecure Monday and ramp up reporting after, just don't want it unattended over the weekend.